# fatal error: opening dependency file

Tags: c, git, makefile, public-key-encryption, contiki

I am trying to use ECC library on contiki os.
But I got a error for dependency. I think the problem is with my Makefile but I am not sure where is wrong.

I downloaded from the source https://github.com/nist-emntg/ecc-light-certificate, but I had problem using `git submodule update` after I `git` clone from the source, so I manually download and paste the contiki file into the contiki folder.
Could this be the problem?

Error message

```
> make TARGET=cooja clean 
rm -f *~ *core core *.srec \
    *.lst *.map \
    *.cprg *.bin *.data contiki*.a *.firmware core-labels.S *.ihex *.ini \
    *.ce *.co
rm -rf 
rm -rf obj_cooja

> make sender-node.cooja TARGET=cooja 
  CC        sender-node.c
sender-node.c: In function 'process_thread_sender_node_process':
sender-node.c:104:11: warning: unused variable 'pubKey' [-Wunused-variable]
mkdir obj_cooja
  CC        ../../../platform/cooja/./contiki-cooja-main.c
../../../platform/cooja/./contiki-cooja-main.c: In function 'contiki_init':
../../../platform/cooja/./contiki-cooja-main.c:230:14: warning: variable 'shortaddr' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
../../../platform/cooja/./contiki-cooja-main.c:288:5: warning: passing argument 1 of 'rimeaddr_copy' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
../../../core/./net/rime/rimeaddr.h:79:6: note: expected 'union rimeaddr_t *' but argument is of type 'uint8_t *'
mv contiki-cooja-main.o obj_cooja/mtype371.o
  CC        ../../../../ecc/ecc.c
../../../../ecc/ecc.c:700:1: fatal error: opening dependency file obj_cooja/../../../../ecc/ecc.d: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [obj_cooja/../../../../ecc/ecc.o] Error 1
Process returned error code 2
```

This is my makefile

```
all: sender-node receiver-node root-node
extra: example tools tests
CONTIKI=../../..

WITH_UIP6=1
UIP_CONF_IPV6=1

include $(CONTIKI)/../Makefile.curve
CURVE_DIR=$(CONTIKI)/../ecc/curve-params
CFLAGS+= -DUIP_CONF_IPV6_RPL\
         -DSHA2_USE_INTTYPES_H \
         -DWITH_SHA256 \
         -D$(DOMAIN_PARAMS) \
         -DTHIRTYTWO_BIT_PROCESSOR \
         -DDOMAIN_PARAMS=$(DOMAIN_PARAMS)

CFLAGS+=-DPROJECT_CONF_H=\"project-conf.h\"

PROJECT_SOURCEFILES += $(CONTIKI)/../ecc/ecc.c $(CONTIKI)/../ecc/ecdsa.c $(CONTIKI)/../ecc/nn.c $(CONTIKI)/../sha2/sha2.c $(CONTIKI)/../certificate/certificate.c
PROJECTDIRS += sha2 ecc $(CURVE_DIR) certificate

include $(CONTIKI)/../ecc/curve-params/Makefile.curve_params

# mc1322x is little endian only
ifeq ($(TARGET),econotag)
CFLAGS+= -DWORDS_LITTLEENDIAN
endif

ifdef WITH_COMPOWER
APPS+=powertrace
CFLAGS+= -DCONTIKIMAC_CONF_COMPOWER=1 -DWITH_COMPOWER=1 -DQUEUEBUF_CONF_NUM=4
endif

ifdef SERVER_REPLY
CFLAGS+=-DSERVER_REPLY=$(SERVER_REPLY)
endif
ifdef PERIOD
CFLAGS+=-DPERIOD=$(PERIOD)
endif

include $(CONTIKI)/Makefile.include
example:
    make -C example

tools:
    make -C tools

tests:
    make -C tests
```

Answer (score 1):

> but I had problem using git submodule update after I `git clone` from the source, so I manually download and paste the contiki file into the contiki folder.

You cannot then just download any contiki file, since the idea of a submodule is to reference an exact SHA1 of another repo.

Try again to clone the main repo, this time with `--recursive` (and make sure to use the latest Git 2.11.1)

```
cd /path/to/ly/local/clone/of/ecc-light-certificate 
cd ..
move ecc-light-certificate ecc-light-certificate.old
git clone --recursive https://github.com/nist-emntg/ecc-light-certificate
```

The error is:

```
no such remote ref 7a493c44edb6952bf82fc808b9dd91c30d49c871 
Fetched in submodule path 'contiki', but it did not contain 7a493c44edb6952bf82fc808b9dd91c30d49c871.  
Direct fetching of that commit failed
```

First: [https://github.com/tcheneau/contiki@7a493c44edb6952bf82fc808b9dd91c30d49c871](https://github.com/tcheneau/contiki/tree/7a493c44edb6952bf82fc808b9dd91c30d49c871) does exist.

However, looking at its [commit page 7a493c4](https://github.com/tcheneau/contiki/commit/7a493c44edb6952bf82fc808b9dd91c30d49c871), you can see it does not belong to any branch or tag: it is a commit still kept in the GitHub remote repo, but *not* fetch by default (because, again, no branch or tag includes it)

You need to open an issue on [`nist-emntg/ecc-light-certificate/issues`](https://github.com/nist-emntg/ecc-light-certificate/issues) project to alert them on that non-existing commit reference for the submodule contiki.

If you look for that commit message, you will find [commit 1396dfd](https://github.com/tcheneau/contiki/commit/1396dfd817424eb7d3218cc6c51186f80b032e9f) from the native [`fix-native-build` branch](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/compare/master...tcheneau:fix-native-build):

```
C:\Users\vonc\prog\git\ecc-light-certificate\contiki>git log --all --grep="prevent the native target"
commit 1396dfd817424eb7d3218cc6c51186f80b032e9f
Author: Tony Cheneau <tony.cheneau@nist.gov>
Date:   Fri Oct 25 17:53:27 2013 -0400

    Fix a typo (?) that would prevent the native target from building the examples.
```

This is typical of a cherry-picked commit.

To solve your current situation, directly checkout the right commit:

```
C:\Users\vonc\prog\git\ecc-light-certificate\contiki>git checkout 1396dfd817424eb7d3218cc6c51186f80b032e9f
Checking out files: 100% (3223/3223), done.
Note: checking out '1396dfd817424eb7d3218cc6c51186f80b032e9f'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

HEAD is now at 1396dfd81... Fix a typo (?) that would prevent the native target from building the examples.

C:\Users\vonc\prog\git\ecc-light-certificate\contiki>git st
HEAD detached at 1396dfd81
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Comment: hi @VonC regarding these command cd /path/to/ly/local/clone/of/ecc-light-certificate 
cd ..
move ecc-light-certificate ecc-light-certificate.old should be used after clone?

Comment: @lol Before: the idea is simply to move your old clone, before cloning again the same repo in the same folder. That will avoid Git failing to clone because the folder name was already there.

Comment: i tried using git clone --recursive. But it has the same issue where it failed to fetched for contiki folder

Comment: @VnoC error: no such remote ref 7a493c44edb6952bf82fc808b9dd91c30d49c871
Fetched in submodule path 'contiki', but it did not contain 7a493c44edb6952bf82fc808b9dd91c30d49c871. Direct fetching of that commit failed.

Comment: @VnoC ok i will alert them. Thanks for the help

Comment: After i tired reclone and checkout from that branch. It seem that i still has the same original issue. This is the message ../../../../ecc/ecc.c:700:1: fatal error: opening dependency file obj_cooja/../../../../ecc/ecc.d: No such file or directory

Comment: @lol that is different, and where your issue will help the ecc-light-certificate: they are referencing an old 2013 contiki commit which manifestly is no longer a good fit for their current master branch.

Comment: i am sorry about this but i don't understand. As i am new to contiki. Now i had to wait for them to resolve this or i had to find a way to work around it?

Comment: @lol No, you can also try and checkout different commits, to see if a more recent contiki one might work. But otherwise, yes, you would need to report to the ecc-light-certificate project that the contiki commit they are still referencing is not working properly.